# Spring boot rest service POST data with double quotes

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

boot 1.4.0 and MongoDB.I am having issue with post data with special characters.We cannot give double quotes in the request JSON so i am passing double quotes using backslash ex)**"hard\"ware"** but the data is storing in MongoDB as it is instead of escaping. I saw the following post [Escaping quotes in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693725/mongodb-escaping-quotes-while-inserting-record) but how can we handle this issue globally across my spring-boot application instead of doing it for every request. Do we have any special request handling helper for this support?

Since this question is generic i am not posting any code sample.Please do let me know if you need any code samples.

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this answer about using servlet filters of intercept handlers

Comment: @ShawnClark could you please share the URL